# Circles in Python - Looking for source that explains the method

Tags: python, geometry

I am currently teaching myself Python by working through a Pac Man program.

In this program, a Pac Man is drawn by using the `TKinter` circle method:

```
screen point = (300, 240)
PACMAN_SCALE = 0.5 
self.gridSize = 30
fillColor = yellow      ## This is actually reflected in RGB values
outlineColor = yellow   ##This is actually reflected in RGB values
endpoints = (0,0)
width = 2

circle(screen_point, PACMAN_SCALE * self.gridSize, fillColor = fillColor, outlineColor =  outlineColor, endpoints = endpoints, width = width)
```

I understand the first 4 arguments of the circle method, but what are the last two: `endpoints` and `width`?

I also had difficulties finding some documentation on the circle method (all I can find is about the oval method).

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Try changing values of those arguments and see what happens.

Comment: Where does this circle method come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tkinter doesn't have a `circle` method. It *does* have a canvas object which has a `draw_oval` method. Most likely, this `circle` method you have is a wrapper around that.

The `width` attribute in your example likely has to do with the width of the outline. However, the `draw_oval` method has no argument for `endpoints`, so they are likely unique to the `circle` method you are calling. You'll have to consult the documentation or implementation of that method to know what it is for.